# How to get value of a object member from a dictionary

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary

```
Dictionary<int, UserSession> UserSessionLookupTable

class UserSession 
{ 
    public int SessionId { get; set; } 
    public string UserName { get; set; } 
    public Guid SessionGuid { get; set; } 
    public DateTime LoginTime { get; set; } 
}
```

How can I retrive the value sessionGuid with `key=1` from dictionary in c#

Comment: That will be `UserSessionLookupTable[1]`

Comment: I need the value of sessionGuid only

Comment: Well, `UserSessionLookupTable[1].SessionGuid`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
var guid = UserSessionLookupTable[1].SessionGuid;
```

Be aware though that if the key is not present in the dictionary you can get an `KeyNotFoundException` thrown.  To avoid this you could do:

```
public Guid GetSessionGuid(int key)
{
    UserSession session; 
    return UserSessionLookupTable.TryGetValue(key, out session) ? session.SessionGuid : null;
}
```

Comment: +1, but add to answer that the indexer can throw exceptions: _KeyNotFoundException_ and _ArgumentNullException_

Comment: Maybe `TryGet` is more idiomatic - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It should be `UserSessionLookupTable[key].SessionGuid`

Comment: You could avoid using try-catch: `UserSession session; return UserSessionLookupTable.TryGetValue(key, out session) ? session.SessionGuid : null;`

Comment: Thanks edited.  Maybe quicker to add your own answer next time :)

Comment: Felt like it was close enough to yours to be a comment.